# MiniMap extension position icon fly out of map

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm using the minimap extension, the position icon fly out of map when i start moving on the first person mode, it's seems like the position is not sync with the camera.

The background is New built forge version 7 viewer and minimap extension.

result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAfX6.jpg

Comment: Checking with Engineering now will get back soon

Comment: @bryanhuang any update? thanks